# Locally Lipschitz and Gâteaux Derivative if and only if Frechet Derivative

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives, lipschitz-functions, gateaux-derivative

Consider $f$ locally Lipschitz. So $f$ is Gâteaux Derivative if and only if $f$ is Frechet Derivative.

PS.: the converse is trivial.

Comment: The statement is incomplete. What is the domain of $f$?

Comment: $f:U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, where $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 2):

Given $x \in U$, let us suppose that there exists $g \in \mathbb R^n$ (the Gâteaux derivative of $f$ at $x$) such that $$\lim_{t \rightarrow 0}\frac {f(x+th)-f(x)-t\langle g,h \rangle}{t}=0$$ for every $h \in \mathbb R^n$.

We want to show that $$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac {f(x+h)-f(x)-\langle g,h \rangle}{\|h\|}=0$$ if $f$ is $L$-Lipschitz at $x$.

If it is not true, there exist $\varepsilon>0$ and a sequence $\{h_n\}$ with $h_n \rightarrow 0$ and $h_n \neq 0$ for every $n$ such that $$\frac {|f(x+h_n)-f(x)-\langle g,h_n \rangle|}{\|h_n\|} \ge \varepsilon$$ (remember the sequential criterium for functional limits)

Since the unit sphere in $\mathbb R^n$ is compact, $\{h_n\}$ admits a subsequence $\{u_n\}$ such that the sequence $\left\{\frac {u_n}{\|u_n\|}\right\}$ converges. Let $t_n=\|u_n\|$, $v_n=\frac {u_n}{\|u_n\|}$ and $v_n \rightarrow v\,$. Note that $t_n \rightarrow 0\,$ and $\|v\|=1$.

The compactness of the unit sphere in $\mathbb R^n$ is essential in this proof and characterizes the Banach spaces of finite dimension.

Then, for $n$ sufficiently large $$\varepsilon \le \frac {|f(x+u_n)-f(x)-\langle g,u_n \rangle|}{\|u_n\|}=$$$$\frac {|f(x+t_nv_n)-f(x)-t_n\langle g,v_n \rangle|}{t_n}=$$$$\frac {|f(x+t_nv_n)-f(x+t_nv)+t_n \langle g,v \rangle-t_n \langle g,v_n \rangle +f(x+t_nv)-f(x)-t_n \langle g,v \rangle|}{t_n} \le $$$$L \cdot \|v_n-v\|+\|g\| \cdot \|v_n-v\|+\frac {|f(x+t_nv)-f(x)-t_n \langle g,v \rangle |}{t_n} \rightarrow 0$$ so $\varepsilon \le 0$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the Gâteaux derivative is required to be linear: this is often, but not always, a part of its definition. Without linearity the claim would be false.

Let's consider differentiability at $a\in\mathbb{R}^n$; we may assume $a=0$ by translation. As often, it helps to subtract off a linear function to achieve $f(0)=0$ and $Df(0)=0$ (where $Df$ is the Gâteaux derivative). The goal is to prove that 
$$\frac{1}{r}\max_{|x| = r} |f(x)| \to 0,\quad r\to0$$
which gives Fréchet derivative.

Let $L$ be the Lipschitz constant of $f$ within the unit ball. 
Given $\epsilon>0$, pick a finite $(\epsilon/L)$-net $N$ within the unit sphere of $\mathbb{R}^n$. By the Gâteaux differentiability, there is $\rho>0$ such that $$|f(r\xi )|/r <\epsilon$$ whenever $r<\rho$ and $\xi\in N$ (the key point is that $N$ is finite).

Observe that every point    $x$ with $|x|=r$ lies within distance $(\epsilon/L) r$ of some point of the form $r\xi$ with $\xi\in N$. Conclude by the Lipschitz property that 
$$|f(x)|\le |f(x)-f(r\xi)|+|f(r\xi)|\le 2   \epsilon r$$

Comment: Do we also assume $a = 0$ here? Seems so given how you've defined gateaux and frechet differentiability and moved from $B_1(a)$ to the unit ball, unless I've missed something. I think everything works anyway, it's a nice proof.

Comment: You're right, I fixed this now.

Comment: @I disagree If $Df$ is the Gâteaux derivative I don't see how you can subtract a linear function to get $Df=0$. Since $Df$ need not be linear... You could get every partial equal to $0$, but you use the stronger fact that the derivative in every direction is $0$. ???

Comment: @David I belong to the school that requires linearity. So does the author of the question, because the statement would be false otherwise. I know this is a contentious matter, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%A2teaux_derivative

Comment: @I disagree Indeed, I just posted an answer saying the statement is false. The author could be simply mistaken. I'm probably all wet, but if  Gâteaux differentiability requires linearity then it seems to me that  Gâteaux differentiability is simply the same as Frechet differentiability. (In the finite-dimensional case, as here). ???

Comment: @I disagree Never mind the stupid question about how a linear  Gâteaux derivative can fail to be a Frechet derivative. Little-oh along every line is not little-oh.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me the result is false.

Say $S$ is the unit circle in $\mathbb R^2$. Say $\phi:S\to\mathbb R$ is any smooth function with $\phi(-x)=\phi(x)$. There's a function $f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ such that

1. $f(x)=\phi(x)\quad(x\in S),$
2. $f(tx)=tf(x)\quad(x\in\mathbb R^2,t\in\mathbb R).$

This seems like a counterexample to me, unless it just happens that $\phi$ is the restriction to $S$ of a linear functional. What am I missing?

Comment: You're not missing anything. Your example confirms that the claim is false if the Gâteaux derivative is not required to be linear.